# Меню с задаваемым позиционированием элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ui

Столкнулся вот с такой задачей - нужен контрол (меню, тулбар, и т.д.) который может позиционировать элементы внутри себя - слева / по центру / справа.
Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

[image: Схематический вид такого элемента]

Кроме позиционирования, нужно реализовать панель переполнения - когда элементу не достаточно места для отображения, он переходит в панель переполнения, которая открывается в попапе (по аналогии с тулбаром). Панель переполнения одна для всех 3 груп элементов.

Пробовал сделать свою панель для меню, которая будет позиционировать элементы используя свойство HorizontalAllightment. Для этого создал наследника от Panel и использовал исходники StackPanel чтобы задать логику методов MeasureOverride и ArrangeOverride.

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var panelDesiredSize = new Size();
        var children = this.InternalChildren;
        var layoutSlotSize = constraint;
        this.lastLeftElementIndex = -1;
        this.lastCenterElementIndex = -1;
        this.lastRightElementIndex = -1;

        layoutSlotSize.Width = double.PositiveInfinity;
        var w = 0d;

        for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (!(children[i] is FrameworkElement child))
            {
                continue;
            }                

            child.Measure(layoutSlotSize);
            var childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;

            panelDesiredSize.Width += childDesiredSize.Width;
            panelDesiredSize.Height = Math.Max(panelDesiredSize.Height, childDesiredSize.Height);

            switch (child.HorizontalAlignment)
            {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                    lastCenterElementIndex = i;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    lastRightElementIndex = i;
                    w += childDesiredSize.Width;
                    break;
                default:
                    lastLeftElementIndex = i;
                    w -= childDesiredSize.Width;
                    break;
            }
        }

        var emptySpaceWidth = constraint.Width - panelDesiredSize.Width;
        this.leftFillerWidth = (emptySpaceWidth + w) / 2d;
        this.rightFillerWidth = emptySpaceWidth - this.leftFillerWidth;
        return new Size(constraint.Width, panelDesiredSize.Height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var children = this.InternalChildren;
        var rectChild = new Rect(arrangeSize);
        double previousChildSize = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.lastLeftElementIndex + 1; ++i)
        {
            if (!(children[i] is FrameworkElement f))
            {
                continue;
            }

            rectChild.X += previousChildSize;
            previousChildSize = f.DesiredSize.Width;
            rectChild.Width = previousChildSize;
            rectChild.Height = Math.Max(arrangeSize.Height, f.DesiredSize.Height);

            f.Arrange(rectChild);
        }

        rectChild.X += this.leftFillerWidth;
        previousChildSize = 0d;

        for (int i = this.lastLeftElementIndex + 1; i < this.lastCenterElementIndex + 1; ++i)
        {
            if (!(children[i] is FrameworkElement f))
            {
                continue;
            }

            rectChild.X += previousChildSize;
            previousChildSize = f.DesiredSize.Width;
            rectChild.Width = previousChildSize;
            rectChild.Height = Math.Max(arrangeSize.Height, f.DesiredSize.Height);

            f.Arrange(rectChild);
        }

        rectChild.X += this.rightFillerWidth;
        previousChildSize = 0d;

        for (int i = this.lastCenterElementIndex + 1; i < this.lastRightElementIndex + 1; ++i)
        {
            if (!(children[i] is FrameworkElement f))
            {
                continue;
            }

            rectChild.X += previousChildSize;
            previousChildSize = f.DesiredSize.Width;
            rectChild.Width = previousChildSize;
            rectChild.Height = Math.Max(arrangeSize.Height, f.DesiredSize.Height);

            f.Arrange(rectChild);
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что constraint.Width имеет значение PositiveInfinity и поэтому не получается вычислить значение ширины заполнителей. И более того, если возвращать из MeasureOverride значение, в котором width = constraint.Width то получаем исключение (не можем возвращать из этого метода бесконечность).

Еще есть идея сделать контрол с гридом, который содержит 3 меню. Но не уверен, что получится правильно позиционировать центральную группу элементов. И еще не придумал как связать 3 меню с одной панелью перепаолнения.

Сталкивался кто с такой задачей? В сторону чего смотреть?

Comment: Я сталкивался, и кажется даже отвечал на похожий вопрос. Поищу по архивам.

Comment: Через поиск не нашел, может не так искал.

Comment: думаю, что нужно создавать свой контрол

Comment: Это не проблема, но нужно знать в сторону чего смотреть. Пока нет четкого представления как реализовать позиционирование групп (центральная и правая) и подвязать панель переполнения к всем группам.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/873210/10105), там решается более сложная проблема.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Ваш подход с `MeasureOverride` и `ArrangeOverride` в общем-то правильный. Но там внутри есть ещё «подковёрные игры» с `Min/MaxLength`, и `IsOverflowItem`, их нужно тоже аккуратно перенести. В общем, смотрите в код, дерзайте. Задание у вас не сложное, но требует вдумчивой аккуратности. Спрашивайте, если что.

Comment: @VladD исходники тулбара тоже смотрел. На их основе буду думать решение для панели переполнения. Моя задача немного расходится с концепцией WPF - элементы могут увеличиваться в зависимости от своего содержимого. Мне же  нужно изначально знать размер, в который будет вписан мой контрол, чтобы по этим размерам спозиционировать элементы по группам. Недавно похожую задачу (позиционирование слева и справа) решил через DockPanel и 2 Menu, но это довольно кустарное решение.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Ну по идее такая же логика и у WPF? Только по размеру элементов, которым необходимо быть в главной панели, вычисляется `MinLength` (это важно).

Comment: @VladD MinLength - по размеру элементов в основной панели, MaxLength - с учетом из панели переполнения, т.е. размер тулбара определяется по его содержимому. Я пробовал другой подход - вычислял размер всего содержимого и пробовал его разместить на всей панели (добавляя заполнители между левой-центральной и центральной-правой групой). Но у меня это не получилось - для вычисления ширины заполнителей нужно знать ширину меню, которое содержит панель. А вот ее я и не знаю. Вот думаю может есть другой подход для этого. (Сам думаю в сторону грида посмотреть еще)

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Смотрите, там не всё так плохо. У элемента тулбара может быть параметр `Toolbar.OverflowMode = Never`, при этом он _никогда_ не должен попадать в панель переполнения. Это значит, что по любому минимальная длина тулбара равна сумме длин таких вот элементов. Если у вас таких элементов нет, то `MinLength = 0`. А `MaxLength` у вас будет по идее бесконечным, т. к. вы хотите дать тулбару как угодно растянуться, верно? То есть у вас как бы возможны дыры, да?

Comment: @VladD, да, это была моя первая идея - вычислить место под элементы, найти разницу между размером меню и размером его элементов, и эту разницу использовать для двух "дыр" в панели меню. Таким образом нужные мне группы элементов будут правильно размещены. Но данная идея не сработала. Теперь думаю использовать грид с тремя столбцами, внутри каждого содержится меню. А позже переделать это в один контрол.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: А почему не сработала? Вроде нормальная идея. Ну только в MeasureOverride нужно возвращать что-то другое.

Comment: @Vlad, я не знаю размера меню когда вычисляю размер содержимого меню. Соответственно не могу вычислить размеры заполнителей.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: К вам приходит размер в ArrangeOverride, там и можно вычислить размеры заполнителей.

Comment: @Vlad в ArrangeOverride приходит размер полученный в MesureOverride, т.е. размер содержимого панели. Но вот что нашел - сначала вызывается MeasureOverride для меню, потом для его панели. В MeasureOverride для меню приходит нужное значение ширины меню. Попробую чтото с этим сделать.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Что-то как-то слишком сложно у вас выходит. Ну то есть понятно, что в самом начале ваша панель будет минимального возможного размера, но её ж потом можно растягивать мышкой. Максимальный возможный размер вам Toolbar не даёт потому, что о небось и сам маленький, и не растягивается автоматически. Посмотрите на анимацию [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873767/10105). А какого поведения вы хотите от ToolbarTray (это внешняя панель, которая содержит Toolbar'ы)?

Comment: @VladD По поведению мне больше элемент Menu подходит - есть строка, ширина которой равна ширине главного окна. В этой строке есть элементы с разным выравниванием, мышкой размер строки не изменяется, но изменяется при изменении ширины главного окна. Главной проблемой у меня было отсутствие значения ширины предка. Сейчас осталось разобратся с логикой в ArrangeOverride и получу то, что нужно.

Comment: Разобрался с позиционированием, все остальное, в теории, ясно. Как доведу до ума - опубликую решение.

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов: Отлично! Очень хорошо, что разобрались!